# What happens to the request stream in node before it is consumed?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am working on a node application where I pipe a post request's body into a writable stream that saves the data to disk. I realized while building this application that I have no idea what actually happens to the request stream before it is consumed. Say I did something like this:

```
app.post('/api/data', (req, res) => {
  const writableStream = fs.createWriteStream('data.txt');
  setTimeout(() => {
    req.pipe(writableStream);
  }, 3000);
});
```

What is actually happening to the stream in the 3 seconds between when the request is initially received and when the stream starts being piped? Is it being loaded into memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Streams support a buffer for incoming data, but when the buffer fills up, they tell the sender to stop sending more data until they are ready for some more.

Since an incoming request is actually a TCP connection and incoming data is data arriving on the TCP connection, this probably turns into more a question about what happens to incoming TCP data when you aren't reading the data as fast as it wants to arrive.  The answer is that TCP supports flow/control where the receiver tells the sender to stop sending data for the moment and then when incoming buffers clear, it tells the sender it can start sending data again.

Here's a [quick overview](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Flow_control) of TCP flow control.

In your specific stream coding example, until you issue the `req.pipe()`, there are no data listeners on the stream so it has nothing to do with incoming data.  Thus, it will fill up its buffers from the incoming TCP stream, stop reading more from the incoming TCP socket (which will trigger TCP flow control).  Then, when you run the `req.pipe()` that automatically registers handlers for `data` events and the stream will start triggering those events.  As data is read out of the stream buffer, it will then be able to accept more incoming data from the TCP socket which will allow TCP to tell the other end of the TCP socket to restart the incoming flow of new data and so on.

There's a lot more here about how readable streams work: http://www.sitepoint.com/basics-node-js-streams/ and how they can be paused or resumed.

Comment: Awesome response. Thanks so much for clarifying.

Comment: @user2689931 - I added a bit more about your specific coding example.